# LOCATING FILES USING MULTIPLE STRING AND DATE CRITERIA

Tags: string, powershell, filter

I am trying to use a code as follows, to locate files with specific strings, extension and lastwritetime :

```
get-childitem C:\users\nila9\Downloads -filter *.mkv -recurse 
    | where-object { $_.Name -match ("*bluray*" -and "*1080*") -and $_.lastwritetime -match "11/20/2020" }
```

The code is meant to first filter all files in the downloads folder with the extension `*.mkv` and then further shortlist for filenames containing the string "bluray" and "1080" and modified after the specified date.

While this code does not return any error, it does however not execute and releases the control to the prompt.

Is there someplace I am getting it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: read the docs on the `-match` operator. it uses _regex_ not what you used. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) pointed out, `-match` uses regex and needs a different syntax. Your code needs a different operator that handles wildcards (`*`) and for that, there is `-like`

Also, you should not try to compare a DateTime object with a string, so `-match` is no good for that either.

If a filename needs BOTH `bluray` **AND** `1080`, you can change the code to

```
$refDate = (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 11 -Day 20).Date  # set time part to all 0 (--> midnight)
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\nila9\Downloads' -Filter '*.mkv' -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*bluray*" -and $_.Name -like "*1080*" -and $_.LastWriteTime -ge $refDate }
```

If however the file needs to have `bluray` **OR** `1080` in its name, you *can* use `-match` on that part:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 11 -Day 20).Date  # set time part to all 0 (--> midnight)
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\nila9\Downloads' -Filter '*.mkv' -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match "bluray|1080" -and $_.LastWriteTime -ge $refDate }
```

<sup>The pipe symbol `|` in regex is the OR operator</sup>